# Sending messages from the application to twitter in certain conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can application send a message in twitter without user intervention under certain conditions? For example when charging the battery less 10%?
please, sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor battery level like so:

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
device.batteryMonitoringEnabled = YES;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification" object:device];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification" object:device];

// Your notification handler
- (void)batteryChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if(device.batteryLevel <= 10)
        [self twittBatteryLevel: device.batteryLevel];
}
```

And then implement -(void)twittBatteryLevel:(float)batteryLevel as you would using twitter API

Comment: Thank you! But can you send the unattended, on behalf of the user?

Comment: He will have to accept you app's authorization to twitt in it's name of course, but only while setting app twitter account

Comment: without confirmation of sending a message? thank you very much!you really helped me a lot!

Comment: Don't hesitate to select the answer as correct if so